# Does Java8 SSLSocketFactory obey the relevant network proxy properties?

Tags: java-8, tls1.2, http-proxy, sslsocketfactory

I'm wondering whether `SSLSocketFactory` provides out of the box support for network proxies as documented here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#Proxies

i.e. is communication through sockets created with `sslSocketFactory.createSocket()`... supposed to be proxied as expected?

My local tests show that this is not the case but before digging deeper I wanted to clarify whether support exists in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28035322/469154) says `java.net.Proxy`, or the `https.proxyHost/proxyPort properties`, only support HTTP proxying via `HttpURLConnection`, not via a `Socket`.

The answer seems to be **NO**!